# How do you redirect a reputable domain name to a spelling variation without losing SEO value?

Tags: seo, google-search, 301-redirect, google-news

We have a reputable news domain which is about 17 years old. We want to redirect this domain from `example-all.tld` to `exampleall.tld`. We will implement a 301 permanent redirect for all URLs.

Now traffic is coming from search on Google for the brand name and business keywords.  For these keywords we are first in the search results for pretty much all search engines.  We have many organic backlinks for example-all.com domain, Moz Domain Authority 64 & Page Authority 70.

When we redirect the domain, what types of SEO problems will befall the website? Will we get the same value of previous domain for backlinks, Google search, reputation, etc?  Is there any other method for this redirect from an SEO perspective?